# How to insert my records before the deletion is execute (record logs)?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

How to insert my records before the deletion is execute (record logs)?
I am using SQL PDO PHP.

Here is my code for delete:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDFU4.png): [image: Code for deletion]

Here is my code for insert:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhQ6g.png): [image: Code for insert]

Comment: Do the insert before delete?

Comment: Yes, insert first before delete.

Comment: Your question is not clear I am assuming u want to insert and delete with the same form? If so, then its kinda weird that u want to accomplish two separate tasks with same form

Comment: I want to delete a specific record then add the deleted records to another table in short (record logs)

Comment: As per [ask] please do not include images of code. [Edit] your question to provide a [mre] of your issue as text, as well as a clear explanation of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: `I want to delete a specific record then add the deleted records`...so just do all that in one script, sequentially. It's unclear why that would be a difficulty.

Comment: ITs easy to say that.

Comment: why bother? just add a field called deleted and simply update that field to 1. Then select only fields what not deleted